# Very simple "update password" form with Rails/Devise, comes back with a 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 4 with Devise. I have a very simple form that should allow the user to update their password.

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: edit_user_registration_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group current-password-container">
    <%= f.label :current_password, "Old password", class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
        <%= f.text_field :current_password, class: "form-control", data: { errorclass: "current-password-container" } %>
      </div>
      <div id="current-password-container-validation-message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group password-container">
    <%= f.label :password, "New password", class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
        <%= f.text_field :password, class: "form-control", data: { errorclass: "password-container" } %>
      </div>
      <div id="password-container-validation-message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group password-confirmation-container">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password", class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
        <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", data: { errorclass: "password-confirmation-container" } %>
      </div>
      <div id="password-confirmation-container-validation-message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Update Password", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the routes file:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/sign_in", to: "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  authenticated :user do
    devise_scope :user do
      root to: "users/agents/dashboard#index", as: :authenticated_root
    end
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    devise_scope :user do
      root to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :root
    end
  end

  namespace :users do
    namespace :agents do
      resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
      resources :account
      resources :bonds
    end
  end
```

The error I get back is the following:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/users/edit")`

And my custom controller is blank (so it should default to using super on every method).

What is going on with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the type of request to submit a form is POST, but

```
edit_user_registration_path
```

only match a get request, so you surely get that route error.

The post request should be

```
user_registration_path(current_user)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are indeed correct (except I didn't need `as: resource_name`), I just needed to use `user_registration_path`. If you edit your answer to just be the second part (starting at "In your case,"), I'll gladly accept!

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. I change the first part, removed  as: resource_name.